# going from one view to the next in swift

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift

i have 2 buttons that are supposed to switch between view controller1 and view controller2. when i click on my button to switch over to the second view controller i keep getting the error: fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

```
var settings : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))

    settings.setTitle("S", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    settings.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    settings.center = (CGPointMake(120, 30))
    settings.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    settings.addTarget(self, action: "settingsBar:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    settings.layer.borderWidth = 3
    settings.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    view.addSubview(settings)

@IBAction func settingsBar(sender: AnyObject){

    let view2 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as?
        ViewController2
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you told us the actual line where you are getting the error, but I am assuming it is on:

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
```

There are three reasons you might get that error on that line. Both have to do with `view2` being `nil` when `pushViewController` expects it not to be.

1. There is no view controller in your storyboard named "view2": That would result in the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returning `nil`. Then `view2` would be `nil` and when `pushViewController` tries to push `nil`, you get the error
2. The view controller named "view2" is not of the type `ViewController2`. In that case, the conversion using `as?` will return `nil` also causing `pushViewController` to assert
3. Your view controller (the one the code in your question is from) is not actually embedded in a navigation controller. That would result in `self.navigationController` being `nil`. When you try to call `pushViewController` on `nil`, you get your error

Comment: i do have a view controller set to ViewController2 with the identity set to view2

Comment: @user3856516 I forgot about a third reason you could get that error. I updated my answer.